# converting array to strings in sentence

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am just trying to convert some user id's to usernames in from an sql database. I know I shouldn't be using mySQl. I plan on switching over to PDO shortly...

```
  $getuseridsquery= "SELECT users.username FROM users WHERE users.id IN(". implode( ",", $uids) .")";
  echo $getuseridsquery;
  $getuseridsresult = mysql_query($getuseridsquery);
  $getuseridsresult1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getuseridsresult);
  var_dump($getuseridsresult1);
  echo $getuseridsresult1;

  print '<p>Conversation between ';
  print implode(', ', $getuseridresult1) . ' and ' . $last;
  echo '.</p>';
```

I am getting:

```
 array (size=1)
  'username' => string 'ambe5950' (length=8)
```

when I var dump, so I just need to figure  out how to convert that to the sentence below.

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert that to the sentence"?  What problem are you having here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `username` part of that output is the index/key in your array. This is akin to what other languages call a `Map` or a `Dictionary`, but PHP allows for non-integer indexes in arrays. Simply put, you need to access the value via its index, which in this case is "username":

```
$username = $getuseridsresult1['username'];
echo $username; //prints "ambe5960"
```

Also if you're not moving to PDO yet, then you should at the very least change `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`.

Comment: hey, thanks so much. I was probably going to jump straight to PDO. My site is not live yet, so I have some time to decide.

Comment: Is there any way to print those as a list, so they can all be contained in one variable? That first part worked great for, but sometimes, there can be more than two people in a conversation, so

Comment: When you get an array, try continuing to use the `var_dump` and see if you notice any patterns that you can work with, since I'm not personally familiar with the output for everything you have. Also look into `for` and `foreach` loops, as that will help you traverse arrays.